# How to upload and deploy java web application (war file) on remote server?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, server, war

I exported my java web application to .war file. I need to upload this application on a remote server that run Apache. I usually use Fugu FTP application to upload files on the server. How I can upload and deploy my Java Web Application to my server?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your are using Apache Tomcat. If you drop the .WAR file into the Tomcat webapps/ folder it will auto explode and deploy.

If you have access to the Tomcat Manager url, you can use it to upload and deploy the .WAR file.

Comment: Yes i'm using Tomcat. If I drop it to the webapps folder, I can only access it via `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/`. However, I need to host it on another server that has Apache on it. How I can do that?

Comment: If you have the Apache web server, you can proxy your requests to the tomcat server through that. You need a Java webserver to server your .WAR servlets/JSP's

Comment: Sorry I did get what you mean. Could you please explain how I can proxy my requests to the tomcat through that?